# Filling an Array of structs from a .dat File C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, fstream

I am working on a simple program that requires an array of structures be filled with information from a .dat file. Rather than a lengthy explanation I will simply show you exactly what the problem is.

Here is the relevant code: C++, compiling in Redhat.

```
// Pre-main
struct Property{
  string name;
  int owner;
  int cost;
  int rent; 
};

const int BOARD_SIZE = 45;
const string FILE_NAME = "MNinput.dat";


// Within main
ifstream inFile;
Property boardInfo[BOARD_SIZE];
int count = 0;

inFile.open(FILE_NAME.c_str());

while(count < BOARD_SIZE && getline(inFile, boardInfo[count].name)){
  inFile >> boardInfo[count].owner
         >> boardInfo[count].cost
         >> boardInfo[count].rent;
  count++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
  cout << boardInfo[i].name << endl
       << boardInfo[i].owner << endl
       << boardInfo[i].cost << endl
       << boardInfo[i].rent << endl << endl;
}
```

I am positive the file is opening properly.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9cnLGYwoO2aV0tUeHlPLU04dUU/edit?usp=sharing) is the data file (open with notepad++ or similar)

Here is the output I am getting. Instead of printing the entire array, I get the following

[image: Output for code as shown]

Again I am certain that the file is being opened properly and that the rest of the code is correct. But if you want to see the entire source code file, just ask.

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advanced!

**EDIT: Debugging info as requested**

**Tried** removing all spaces from the .dat file. Same exact output as before.

**Tried** using `while(count < BOARD_SIZE && inFile >> boardInfo[count].name)` instead of `while(count < BOARD_SIZE && getline(inFile, boardInfo[count].name))`
The result: With and without spaces in .dat file

[image]

**Tried** loading just a small number of entries from the data file, first 3
 then 4 then 5
Here is the result from loading just 3 entries (4 and 5 entries yields a similar result with number sequences replacing all of the actual values).

[image]

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Apologies. What am I doing wrong that causes either the for-loop to not print the entire array or the while-loop to not properly populate the values in the array from the .dat file.

Comment: Spend some time debugging (with breakpoints) and you may have a more specific question than "what is wrong?"

Comment: Will do. I just wanted to make a first pass to see if I'd missed anything obvious. I'll post the results shortly.

Comment: Updated the OP with the debugging attempts. It seems as if after the first entry it is printing memory addresses instead of the values? Also except for the first entry it always leaves the string value of each structure blank. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to put an `inFile.ignore();` to clear the filestream since I was mixing `getline(inFile, )` and `inFile >>`